# What are Exchange IMAP capabilities?

Tags: exchange, imap

Having failed to find anything relevant about the state of IMAP in Exchange 2010 product line in Microsoft Knowledge Base  i'm wondering if anyone has any input on what IMAP extensions are supported. A 'semi standart' IMAP CAPABILITIES list returned by Exchange after user login would be extra handy. I'm particulary interested in such extensions as SORT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848256.aspx
http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc5256.html

Above technet link is the nearest i could get, I haven't thought about it myself but your question made me curious, however on technet page it says that an rfc may refer to some thing differently and it may or may not be implemented by microsoft in exactly the same way - so the best thing they suggest is to open a question with MS Support or you can post a question on technet forums.

Hope that Helps

Answer (score 3):

I happened to researching something similar, here is a snippet from my mutt debug log connecting to an Exchange 2010 client access server:

```
[2012-06-13 19:50:48] 4< * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
[2012-06-13 19:50:48] IMAP queue drained
[2012-06-13 19:50:48] 4> a0000 CAPABILITY
[2012-06-13 19:50:48] 4< * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
```

Comment: Pretty accurate. The only issue with Exchange IMAP in certain cases is the violation of the `RFC822.SIZE` value. It can corrupt attachments with certain clients (e.g. Thunderbird). [Fix/workaround here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191504). Oh, and "Go Illini"!